# Spring ehcache - Not able to retrieve value based on custom key

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I am using `KeyGenerator` to generate custom key while caching a component.
Here is the cacheable method:

`@CachePut(value = "cacheOne", keyGenerator = "keyGenerator")
    public CachedObject cacheMeta(final Object obj1,
            final Object obj2,
            final CachedObject cachedObject) {
        return cachedObject;
}`

Here is `KeyGenerator` implementation:

`public Object generate(Object o, Method m ,Object ... params){
StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
return s.append(params[0].hashCode()).append(params[1].hashCode());
}`

While retrieving value from cache, i am generating key as :

`StringBuilder s= new StringBuilder();
s.append(obj1.hashCode().append(obj2.hashCode()));
Element elt=CacheManager.getInstance("cacheOne").get(s)`

But it always returns null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a `StringBuilder` as the cache key. `StringBuilder` has no `equals` or `hashCode` defined. So it relies on the ones defined on `Object`.

Which basically means that the get used to get the cache entry doesn't match the one putting the entry.

Using `toString()` to put

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
return s.append(params[0].hashCode()).append(params[1].hashCode()).toString();
```

and get

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.append("a".hashCode()).append("b".hashCode());
Cache.ValueWrapper wrapper = cache.get(s.toString());
```

solves it.

But I have to things to say.

First, using a `StringBuilder` here is useless because using String concatenation will let the compiler add a `StringBuilder` under the hood but be much nicer to read. So you could do

```
return params[0].hashCode() + "" + params[1].hashCode();
```

and

```
Cache.ValueWrapper wrapper = cache.get("a".hashCode() + "" + "b".hashCode());
```

which will work perfectly and have the same performance.

Then, relying on hashcodes to create a key is not safe. Hashcodes can have collisions. Even when appending two hashcodes. So you might mix entries on a given key.